# How we can implement Auto rename tag feature in monaco editor similar to AutoRenameTag extension of vscode?

Tags: vscode-extensions, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

**Question**:
I am working with Monaco Editor and I want to add an "Auto Rename Tag" feature, similar to the functionality provided by the AutoRenameTag extension in Visual Studio Code. This means that when a user edits the opening tag, the corresponding closing tag should be automatically updated, and vice versa. How can I implement this feature in Monaco Editor?

**Problem Details:**
I have been exploring Monaco Editor and trying to figure out how to enable the "Auto Rename Tag" feature, but I haven't found any built-in support for it. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. I've included Monaco Editor in my project.
2. I've looked through the Monaco Editor documentation but didn't find any direct mention of the "Auto Rename Tag" feature.
3. I've also searched for third-party plugins or extensions, but none seem to provide this specific functionality.
4. I've examined the Monaco Editor source code, but I'm not sure where to start in implementing this feature.

**What I've Tried:**
I attempted to create a custom extension for Monaco Editor, but I'm not sure how to approach this feature. I have some experience with web development and JavaScript, so I'm willing to dig into the code and work on a solution if someone can guide me in the right direction.

**Expected Outcome:**
I'm looking for guidance or code examples on how to implement the "Auto Rename Tag" feature in Monaco Editor, or at least some pointers on where to start and what functions or APIs to focus on.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!